# Varying number of records

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am executing a SQL Server stored procedure from my C# code which essentially pulls some data from a database based on the supplied condition.

```
DataSet GetAllxxxxxByDate(string entityValue,string companyValue)
{
    using (var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
        {
            var data = new DataSet();
            cmd.CommandText = “myStoredprodecure”;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Connection = sqlConn;

            var eVal = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entityValue) ? string.Empty : entityValue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@entity_value", eVal);

            var company = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(companyValue) ? string.Empty : companyValue;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", company);

            var sqlDataAdaptor = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            sqlDataAdaptor.Fill(data);

            return data;
         }
     }
}
```

Here `entityValue`, `companyValue` are comma separated strings, formed dynamically within C# code and pass it to stored procedure.

Eg:

```
’first’,’second’,’third’
```

And the stored procedure uses these values to fill the `NOT IN` condition defined within it.

The issue is that, I am getting inconsistent number of records when I execute the code.

Following is a quick screenshot where first `WHERE` clause return 3 records and second `WHERE` clause return 1 record. The input values for the first `WHERE` clause is been filled from c# code and the second is been filled manually to test.

[image: Both c# execution result and manual execution result]

The only difference, which I can spot is number of quotes.

Question: can someone help me to zero in the issue or the difference in these give `WHERE` clause ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't show what `entity_value` is in your results, but the difference between the two is you're adding single quotes around the literal values:

`N'''FSEC'''` in SQL is the literal valiue `'FSEC'`

`'FSEC'` in SQL is just `FSEC` (without the quotes).

My guess is that records 2004981 and 2004982 have a value of `FSEC` (without the quotes) for `entity_value`.

If you're adding parameter values from C# code, don't add quotes around them like you would if you were building a string.  SQL will treat the values as strings without needing string qualifiers.

**EDIT**

Okay, I just read this statement:

> Here entityValue, companyValue are comma separated string

You can't just pass in a comma-delimited string to an IN clause.  To search for multiple values there are a few options:

- Add commas to each end and use LIKE:

  ```
  Where (',' + @entity_value +',' LIKE '%,' + entity_value + ',%')
  ```
- Parse the string into a temporary table, than use that table in your IN clause
- Pass the values as a table-valued parameter and use that in your IN clause.
- Build the SQL statement as a string and execute it with `EXEC`

Comment: @D Stanley's assessment seems correct to me. 'entityValue' is probably holding the value ['FSEC'] instead of [FSEC]. You may try to change the part of your code that calls GetAllxxxxxByDate, or, in lieu of that, strip the variable of its leading and ending single quote characters.

Comment: @Nair, you are creating dynamic sql in your SP? And your `NOT IN` is created from the comma separated parameter?

Comment: @unlimit,The only dynamic part is the value which goes into the WHERE class; specifically WHERE NOT IN ("dynamic value")

Comment: @Nair, I think @D Stanley is correct. You must have records with `'FSEC'` and `FSEC`.

Comment: @Nair - read my update.  You can't just put a comma-delimited string in a parameter value in an IN clause.  You have to parse it or find another way to use the list.

Comment: I now skip all single quotes from individual values. And its works. Thanks for all who contributed to my thread.